# Timeline chart with highcharts using x-range with multiple stacks

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to create a timeline chart which shows the flow of different "states" over time. The current implementation is at http://jsfiddle.net/hq1kdpmo/8/ and it looks like [image: state chart].

The current code is as follows:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  "chart": {
    "type": "xrange"
  },
  "title": {
    "text": "State Periods"
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "type": "datetime"
  },
  "yAxis": [{
    "title": {
      "text": "Factions"
    },
    "categories": ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
    "reversed": true
  }],
  "plotOptions": {
    "xrange": {
      "borderRadius": 0,
      "borderWidth": 0,
      "grouping": false,
      "dataLabels": {
        "align": "center",
        "enabled": true,
        "format": "{point.name}"
      },
      "colorByPoint": false
    }
  },
  "tooltip": {
    "headerFormat": "<span style=\"font-size: 0.85em\">{point.x} - {point.x2}</span><br/>",
    "pointFormat": "<span style=\"color:{series.color}\">●</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.yCategory}</b><br/>"
  },
  "series": [{
    "name": "State A",
    "pointWidth": 20,
    "data": [{
      "x": 1540430613000,
      "x2": 1540633768100,
      "y": 0
    }, {
      "x": 1540191009000,
      "x2": 1540633768100,
      "y": 1
    }, {
      "x": 1540191009000,
      "x2": 1540530613000,
      "y": 2
    }, {
      "x": 1540530613000,
      "x2": 1540633768100,
      "y": 3
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "State B",
    "pointWidth": 20,
    "data": [{
      "x": 1540191009000,
      "x2": 1540430613000,
      "y": 0
    }, {
      "x": 1540530613000,
      "x2": 1540633768100,
      "y": 2
    }, {
      "x": 1540191009000,
      "x2": 1540330613000,
      "y": 3
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "State C",
    "pointWidth": 20,
    "data": [{
      "x": 1540330613000,
      "x2": 1540530613000,
      "y": 3
    }]
  }],
  "exporting": {
    "enabled": true,
    "sourceWidth": 1200
  }
});
```

Now what I am looking forward to is create something of this sort (pardon my paint skills)[image: chart to be].

Here the categories A to D are the only axis on y. But I would like to group a variable number of parallel ranges. The use case is that there can be multiple states at any point of time and the number of states at any point of time is variable. How do I go on about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this thanks to support from Highcharts themselves. The idea is to set the tick position on the `load` event and use the `labels.formatter` for formatting each individual label.

```
events: {
  load() {
    let labelGroup = document.querySelectorAll('.highcharts-yaxis-labels');
    // nodeValue is distance from top
    let ticks = document.querySelectorAll('.highcharts-yaxis-grid');
    let tickPositions = Array.from(ticks[0].childNodes).map(
        function(node){
            return +node.attributes.d.nodeValue.split(" ")[2];
        }
    );
    let labelPositions = [];
    for(let i =1 ;i<tickPositions.length;i++){
        labelPositions.push((tickPositions[i] + tickPositions[i-1])/2);
    }
    labelGroup[0].childNodes[0].attributes.y.nodeValue = labelPositions[0] + parseFloat(labelGroup[0].childNodes[0].style["font-size"], 10) / 2;
    labelGroup[0].childNodes[1].attributes.y.nodeValue = labelPositions[1] + parseFloat(labelGroup[0].childNodes[1].style["font-size"], 10) / 2;
    labelGroup[0].childNodes[2].attributes.y.nodeValue = labelPositions[2] + parseFloat(labelGroup[0].childNodes[2].style["font-size"], 10) / 2;
    labelGroup[0].childNodes[3].attributes.y.nodeValue = labelPositions[3] + parseFloat(labelGroup[0].childNodes[3].style["font-size"], 10) / 2;
    labelGroup[0].childNodes[4].attributes.y.nodeValue = labelPositions[4] + parseFloat(labelGroup[0].childNodes[4].style["font-size"], 10) / 2;
  }
}
```

And the labels are formatted as:

```
labels: {
  formatter: function() {
    var chart = this.chart,
      axis = this.axis,
      label;

    if (!chart.yaxisLabelIndex) {
      chart.yaxisLabelIndex = 0;
    }
    if (this.value !== -1) {

      label = axis.categories[chart.yaxisLabelIndex];
      chart.yaxisLabelIndex++;

      if (chart.yaxisLabelIndex === groups.length) {
        chart.yaxisLabelIndex = 0;
      }

      return label;
    }
  },
}
```

Fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/yvnp4su0/42/

Answer (score 1):

To create such a chart you will have to add 12 yAxis (0-11) and set proper ticks and labels so that only A-D categories will be plotted. Additionally, adjust [plotOptions.pointPadding](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.xrange.pointPadding) and [plotOptions.groupPadding](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.xrange.groupPadding) properties to set points width automatically (series.pointWidth should be undefined then).

yAxis options:

```
  yAxis: [{
    title: {
      text: "Factions"
    },
    categories: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
    tickPositions: [-1, 2, 5, 8, 11],
    lineWidth: 0,
    labels: {
      y: -20,
      formatter: function() {
        var chart = this.chart,
          axis = this.axis,
          label;

        if (!chart.yaxisLabelIndex) {
          chart.yaxisLabelIndex = 0;
        }

        if (this.value !== -1) {

          label = axis.categories[chart.yaxisLabelIndex];
          chart.yaxisLabelIndex++;

          if (chart.yaxisLabelIndex === 4) {
            chart.yaxisLabelIndex = 0;
          }

          return label;
        }
      },
    },
    reversed: true
  }]
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/s9qefg7t/1/

Comment: Great answer! Although I have a few things I want to clarify.
1. What does `label.y` represent.
2. I want some space between each tick like the original graph. 'groupPadding` and `pointPadding` just reduces the thickness of the bars.
3 The tooltips have become wrong. I guess I can't use `point.yCategory` anymore and have to write some logic to get the correct y label
4. My requirements also states variable number of ranges for each category. Say, 4, 2, 3, 1 instead of 3, 3, 3, 3. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: 1. The y position offset of the label relative to the tick position on the axis. - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.y 2. This options set paddings, so increase them to have space 3. You can use tooltip.formatter - (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter) to create tooltip as you like - add a category property to each point object and use them inside formatter function, see https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/xnwed9mo/. 4. Yes, however it requires different ticks settings.

Comment: Thanks! That explains a lot. So, I created a fiddle for the multiple ranges in each category. But as you might realise, if I have multiple ranges, setting a constant `y` value won't work. I am trying to execute a function to calculate the required value as `y: function() {return -20;}()`. How can I get the current tick? Fiddle for this https://jsfiddle.net/8ou3yp1L/

Comment: You can use Highcharts renderer: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text and plot custom labels exactly where you like (disable default labels).

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in the comment above it is a better idea to use [Highcharts renderer](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text) and add custom labels than manipulate Dom elements as you did in the previous answer, because it is a much cleaner solution.

Disable default labels:

```
  yAxis: [{
    title: {
      text: "Factions",
      margin: 35
    },
    categories: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
    tickPositions: tickPositions,
    lineWidth: 0,
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    reversed: true
  }]
```

Add custom labels in proper positions using renderer:

```
  chart: {
    type: 'xrange',
    height: 500,
    marginLeft: 60,
    events: {
        load: function() {
        this.customLabels = [];
      },
      render: function() {
        var chart = this,
          yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
          categories = yAxis.categories,
          xOffset = 15,
          yOffset = 20,
          xPos = yAxis.left - xOffset,
          tickPositions = yAxis.tickPositions,
          text,
          label,
          yPos,
          tick1Y,
          tick2Y,
          i;

        for (i = 0; i < tickPositions.length - 1; i++) {
            if (chart.customLabels[i]) {
            chart.customLabels[i].destroy();
          }

          tick1Y = yAxis.toPixels(tickPositions[i]);
          tick2Y = yAxis.toPixels(tickPositions[i + 1]);
          yPos = (tick1Y + tick2Y) / 2 + yOffset;
          text = categories[i];

          label = chart.renderer.text(text, xPos, yPos)
            .css({
              color: '#ccc',
              fontSize: '14px'
            })
            .add();

          chart.customLabels[i] = label;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/vkz7o1hw/

Comment: Yes, using the renderer seems to be more "clean". I am implementing this but have stumbled upon an issue where long labels are spilling over the chart https://jsfiddle.net/7L1czde8/ . For ref., this is not happening with the label formatter implementation https://jsfiddle.net/yvnp4su0/45/ .

Comment: Custom labels require a bit more code and logic than editing the default ones. However, it can be done quite simple: https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/y1tob729/1/